# deleteRows in spanner is not working with 4 keys

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-spanner

deleteRows in Spanner is not working with 4 composite keys. Also, the unique id's in the keys are in order as in the table.

const keys = [ [ '1','2','3','4' ] ];
transaction.deleteRows('table name', keys);

transaction commit is not throwing any error but the row is not getting deleted from the table.

Comment: Could you update your question to provide a little more information about your code? I actually tested a bit with the [Getting started with Cloud Spanner in Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/nodejs/) guide and, by catching the transaction, I was able to identify that using, the syntax you used to declare the keys, returned me a FAILED_PRECONDITION error. On the other hand, once I declared the keys as an array of integers (`const keys = [1, 2, 3, 4]`) it did work. It would be nice to see if you're not missing anything else though.

Comment: Could you share a runnable snippet of your code? Using the two lines code you provided I was able to delete a row with a composite key of 4 columns successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As pessolato and Maxim already pointed out, please share a code snippet and the exact output of your code. We believe the Node.js client should already support your use case, but it is not possible to further debug without more details.